# Golang parse form

Tags: go

If I have the following form setup:

```
{{ range $key, $value := .Scores }}
    <input id="{{$value.Id}}_rating__1" type="radio" name="rating[{{$value.Id}}]" value="-1">
    <input id="{{$value.Id}}_rating__0" type="radio" name="rating[{{$value.Id}}]" value="0">
    <input id="{{$value.Id}}_rating__2" type="radio" name="rating[{{$value.Id}}]" value="+1">
{{ end }}
```

How can I then extract that data correctly? Knowing that there `.Scores` can contain multiple structs

```
func categoryViewSubmit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("POST")

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r.Form()) // annot call non-function r.Form (type url.Values)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r.FormValue("rating")) // Returns nothing
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The form keys look like `rating[id]` where `id` is a value identifier.  To get one of the values, call `r.FormValue("rating[id]")` after substituting `id` for an actual id value.

I suggest printing the form to see what's going on:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r.Form)  // No () following Form, Form is not a function
```

The [form](http://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Form) is an [url.Values](http://godoc.org/net/url#Values). An url.Values is a map[string][]string. You can iterate through the form as follows:

```
for key, values := range r.Form {   // range over map
  for _, value := range values {    // range over []string
     fmt.Println(key, value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just one question, is there a way to iterate through that map? I will never know the different `ids`, so I can't substitute it. The only way would be to iterate over all the form data, and grab the `id` from there.

Answer (score 8):

For others that are looking answers for this I found [**Gorilla's schema**](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) really helpful. It allows you to parse forms to structs and has support for arrays and nested structs. When you combine that with [**guregu's null**](https://github.com/guregu/null) package you can easily parse sructs with optional fields.

**Example Go:**

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
    "gopkg.in/guregu/null.v3"
)

type User struct {
    Id            null.Int    `db:"id" json:"id"`
    // Custom mapping for form input "user_name" 
    Name          string      `db:"user_name" json:"user_name" schema:"user_name"`
    EmailAddress  string      `db:"email_address" json:"email_address"`
    OptionalField null.String `db:"optional_field" json:"optional_field"`
}
```

**Example html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="user_name">
    <input type="text" name="EmailAddress">
    <input type="text" name="OptionalField">
</form>
```